# linux shared library to support multi threaded application callbacks

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, shared-libraries

I need to create a shared library which exposes a set of APIs which will be used by multiple processes which might have more than one thread from where the APIs get called.

This shared library in turn uses another 3rd party shared library to which I need to register a callback. The 3rd party library calls the registered callback from a different thread.

I want to know how to block a thread on a call of API defined in my library and release it when I get the callback from the 3rd party library. This locking should not block other thread from calling the same API...!

I'm using pthread library to create my library.

Psudo Code:

### My Library:

```
int lib_init()
{
    register_callback(callback);
}

int lib_deinit()
{
    unregister_callback();
}

int callback(void *)
{
    <unblock the functions>
}

int function1(int, int)
{
    perform_action();
    <should block till I get a callback from 3rd party library>
}

int function2(char, char)
{
    perform_action();
    <should block till I get a callback from 3rd party library>
}
```

### 3rd Party Library:

```
int register_callback(callback)
{
    ....
    launch_thread();
    ....
}

int unregister_callback()
{
    ....
    terminate_thread();
    ....
}

int perform_action()
{
    /* queue action */
}

void* thread(void*arg)
{
    /* perform the action & invoke callback */
    invoke_callback();
}
```

### Application:

```
main()
{
    init_lib();
    ....
    create_new_thread();
    ....
    function1(10, 20);
    ....
    function2('c', 'd');
}

another_thread()
{
    function2('a', 'b');
    ....
}
```

The exact problem I'm not able to solve is what(how) locking mechanism I need to put in place to block the calls to functions defined in my library & wait for callback from 3rd party library provided my library shall be used in a multi-process & multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the plain pthreads interface, you would use condition variables:

```
int lib_init()
{
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    register_callback(callback);
}

int lib_deinit()
{
    unregister_callback();
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
}

int callback(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    result[??] = p;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int function1(int, int)
{
    result[??] = NULL;
    perform_action();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (result[??] == NULL)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int function2(char, char)
{
    result[??] = NULL;
    perform_action();


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (result[??] == NULL)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

`pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks the mutex while it waits.

The `result[??]` is a stand-in for some method, which you'll have to come up with, to link a particular callback invocation to the specific `function1()` or `function2()` call(s) it is relevant to.

Comment: Thanks @caf, I can start my implementation with the sample code you provided...!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11, you may be interested in [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) & friends. You should create a condition variable in your function API, pass it to your callback, register your callback to the 3rd party library, and make your API function wait on it. Then, you can unblock it at the end of your callback.

Pseudocode:

```
void your_API_f()
{
    define std::condition_variable;
    pack it with your callback parameters
    register the callback to 3rd party lib
    invoke 3rd party func
    wait on your condition variable
}

void your_callback(Parameters* p)
{
    do whatever...
    notify p->your_cond_variable you have finished
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best choice by means of availability and standards is probably using Boost:

Boost.threads for the multithreading, and Boost::interprocess for the inter-process communication; have a look at [IPC synchronization mechanisms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html).

For multi-threaded applications, it's very typical to have some kind of Message Queue (bottom of the link above) that takes messages in a thread-safe way from any thread, whilst another thread in an endless loop gets messages from that queue. These messages would typically include some command, some payload, and a pointer to where the executing thread should put their results. That might as well be another boost::interprocess communication structure.

Comment: I cannot use Boost because of environment (platform) in which I need to deploy my library. All I can use is pthread library & I need to write all that is needed to support the library requirements...!

Comment: Thanks to the Boost license, you can simply include all the boost headers and source files you need in your application. That's the same as writing it yourself. Boost is really portable, too.